# Dart Access Nested key value pair like Json without using map

Tags: json, dart

Using Dart v2.8

Trying to print nested Items like JSON as below

```
  var UsrVar = {
        "NamVak": "UsrNam",
        "MblVak": ["9876543210", "9876543212"],
        "MylVak": ["usrnam@gmail.com", "usrnam@yahoo.com"],
        "AdrVak": {
            "AraVak" : "NamPlc",
            "CtyVak": "NamCty",
            "PinVak": 560056,
        }
  };

  print(UsrVar["MylVak"][1]);
  print(UsrVar["AdrVak"]["CtyVak"]);
```

Theabove code show erroer as :

> Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
>
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
>   Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
>   print(UsrNryVar["AdrVak"]["CtyVak"]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys of `UsrVar` are of type `Object`, so you have to cast the returned object to the type you require:

```dart
(UsrVar["MylVak"] as List)[1]
(UsrVar["AdrVak"] as Map)["CtyVak"]
```

It may be helpful to read more about [The Dart type system](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system).